# Updating Build on testflight

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

I am uploading a new app to Testflight in the next two weeks, but I am almost certainly going to run past the 90 day window for user testing with my beta testers. I plan to update the build 2x to avoid this but I am wondering if updates to builds will automatically propagate to the testers' phones or if they're going to have to go back into the app store to re-download a new build.

I found that updates were not automatic in old versions of Testflight but I don't know if this is still the case after the new version came out.

Thanks!