# Testflight How to update a build without trigger a full review?

Tags: ios, testing, testflight

I am planning to build a prototype iOS application over the course of the next few months--let's say until October 1st--that will need frequent updates for iteration and user testing. After the application is approved for Testflight for the first time, I understand that it will be online for 90 days. I need closer to 140 days.
Firstly, what is the best way to update a build without triggering a few review? My understanding is that updates would not require a review and would take 1-2 hours to become visible, but I'm not sure what process is necessary for this, and what the limitations are. Do I need to update the version number and upload in a specific spot? How do I make sure users can download the new build? Should I delete the old one?
Secondly, how do I extend the time limit beyond the 90 days?
The answers might be related.

My question is similar to [this old one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55662410/updating-build-on-testflight), but no-one answered it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make "test builds" available immediately via TestFlight for **Internal Testers** only.

If you're trying to get it to "outside" testers, then updates *will* have to go through Apple review.

From experience -- if you include enough information in the Reviewer Notes field, and you are only doing incremental changes, reviews can get done very quickly.

Note that if you are "updating" a test build with a whole new section to your app, yeah, the reviewer will likely put it through its paces.

Side note: I've also found it never hurts to begin your Reviewer Notes with something like "Hi Reviewer!! Hope you're having a great day! This is a minor update for our testers, fixing a couple layout issues, typos, etc."

---

For your other questions... just update the version number and archive / upload it as normal. It should automatically replace the current TestFlight version (for your testers to download).

Comment: If you update only the build number, but not the version number then in my experience there is no manual review after the first one. This is based only on the fact that the first review for TestFlight takes a day or two but new builds with the same version number are approved immediately.

Comment: This is wrong. @Paulw11 is correct-ish. In 2022 (and this was even the case in 2017) some builds do need app review and some don't. In my case, all of them have the same version number so that's not the common factor. The true answer is probably somewhere between "are we within a few days of the last approved build" and "how much new byte code is there?"